# Add an Attachment to Dynamics CRM Emails with JScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, jscript

How can I add an attachment to an email in Dynamics CRM 2011? 
The attachment is a Base64 PNG. 
Will I need to use

```
ActivityMimeAttachmentSet?
```

I would like to use JScript to display the attachment as an inline image.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **mimeType = "image/png"**

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. I want to be able to use Xrm.Utility or some supported way in Dynamics CRM. I do not know where to add the mimeType and hope that there is a way to do this from CRM. Thanks for the reply.